# openvpn - Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I have this `client ovpn` file like this

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote PUBLIC_IP 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_2CAzflUWmRFturMk name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
KEY
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
KEY
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

and this `server.conf`

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_2CAzflUWmRFturMk.crt
key server_2CAzflUWmRFturMk.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

ufw firewall is disabled and have generated the openvpn client file through [this](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install) script (but have tried many different).

here's the iptables

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_ACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere             *.website.org  state NEW tcp dpt:915
AS0_ACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere             *.website.org  state NEW tcp dpt:914
AS0_ACCEPT  udp  --  anywhere             *.website.org  state NEW udp dpt:917
AS0_ACCEPT  udp  --  anywhere             *.website.org  state NEW udp dpt:916
AS0_WEBACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_WEBACCEPT  tcp  --  anywhere             *.website.org  state NEW tcp dpt:943
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            
AS0_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_IN_PRE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000
AS0_OUT_S2C  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT_LOCAL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_ACCEPT (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             Mico2026WebAppIaaSLinux 
AS0_IN_POST  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_NAT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK or 0x8000000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_POST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.1.0.0/24         
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_PRE (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             link-local/16       
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16      
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12       
AS0_IN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_IN_ROUTE (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK or 0x4000000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT_POST  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT_LOCAL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp redirect
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT_POST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_OUT_S2C (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_OUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_WEBACCEPT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The client is hanging on "waiting for server response" and the server logs this:

openvpn.log

```
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2019
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 ECDH curve prime256v1 added
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.1/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 GID set to nogroup
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 UID set to nobody
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.2 size=252, ipv6=0
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Thu Jun 25 11:50:29 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

and the other log (openvpnas.log)

```
2020-06-25 11:55:39+0000 [-] OVPN 2 OUT: 'Thu Jun 25 11:55:39 2020 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed'
2020-06-25 11:55:39+0000 [-] OVPN 2 OUT: 'Thu Jun 25 11:55:39 2020 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from [AF_INET]IP:55955'
```

and that's the client log

```
2020-06-25 13:56:33.282083 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2020-06-25 13:56:33.282124 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1593086193,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328137 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328327 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]1194
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328479 Socket Buffers: R=[786896->786896] S=[9216->9216]
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328505 UDP link local: (not bound)
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328531 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]SERVERIP:1194
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328575 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1593086195,WAIT,,,,,,
2020-06-25 13:56:35.328919 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
```

My vpn server used to works but I don't know what I did to break it.

I tried also to reinstall openvpn, but don't know how to fix it and let clients connect

Answer (score 0):

just after 4 days I stopped `service openvpnas stop` and everything works now. dont' know why it was started. thank for your support! my bad